# Why there are two users showing in uptime command results?

Tags: macos, mac, users, uptime

When I ran the uptime on my MacBookPro machine I got the following result:

```
Last login: Thu Jun  3 14:43:40 on ttys000
Osama-Gamal-MBP-2:~ iOsama$ uptime
14:49  up 7 days, 20:10, 2 users, load averages: 0.29 0.24 0.24
```

Why it lists that there are two users? is it normal? and who is the other user, is it the root user or what?

PS: I'm using Mac OS X 10.6.3
Edit: w command output:

```
Osama-Gamal-MBP-2:~ iOsama$ w
 0:41  up 8 days,  6:03, 2 users, load averages: 1.92 1.81 1.38
USER     TTY      FROM              LOGIN@  IDLE WHAT
iOsama   console  -                26May10 8days -
iOsama   s000     -                 0:13       - w
```

who command output:

```
Osama-Gamal-MBP-2:~ iOsama$ who
iOsama   console  May 26 18:40 
iOsama   ttys000  Jun  4 00:13
```

Comment: Can you post the output of `who` ?

Comment: And/or `last`..?

Comment: added to the question

Comment: if you want to kill the session: `$ pkill -9 -t pts/1`
to the the active session: `$ w`

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Try the `w` command. On my system I have the following:

```
# w
 02:16:53 up  6:48,  2 users,  load average: 0.50, 0.42, 0.52
USER     TTY      FROM              LOGIN@   IDLE   JCPU   PCPU WHAT
pcm      tty7     :0               19:28    6:48m 16:07   0.17s gnome-session
pcm      pts/0    :0.0             01:51    0.00s  0.36s  0.76s gnome-terminal
# uptime
 02:16:56 up  6:48,  2 users,  load average: 0.50, 0.42, 0.52
```

tty7 is your desktop login, pts/0 is a pseudo terminal ... probably what was used to type `uptime` in.

> Why it lists that there are two users?

Because it shows every logged in session. A single user can have multiple active sessions at any one time.

> is it normal?

100% normal ... A-OK

> and who is the other user, is it the root user or what?

The other user is yourself. You have multiple sessions running. You can see in your output from your question, that the user name is the same for both sessions.

Comment: Added to the question

Comment: Is something missing from this answer?

Comment: I have multiple Terminal.App windows open on my workstation. `uptime` says there are 8 users on my system, but each of them is tied to one of my Terminal sessions : `17:08  up  8:42, 8 users, load averages: 0.68 0.60 0.58`

Comment: Nope nothing missing .. seems that Stefan said .. it is linked with the number of terminals ..

I opened multiple terminal tabs and checked the uptime found out 5 users!!

Comment: "Stefan said" ... ?? uh ya, that is exactly what is in the answer

Comment: There can be other users too like *_mbsetupuser*, who appears between an update and rebooting to complete the update.

Comment: I am seeing the same output and only logged in once and only one terminal window. I'm guessing there's another reason why MacOS shows two logins.

Answer (score 2):

I have just figured it out! I don't know whether it'll work for you or not. But I did the following steps:

1. Pressed *ctrl+alt+f1* and got terminal emulator on my linux mint 20.1 (Cinnamon)
2. Typed *exit* and hit enter
3. Opened **Terminal**; typed *uptime* and hit enter
   Now, it was showing me 1 user instead of 2. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Each Terminal window or tab adds an additional user to what uptime reports. So, I'm guessing that one of those users is for your current Terminal session, and the other is for your macOS.