# Snow Leopard reports other users, but who are they?

Tags: mac, osx-snow-leopard, security, user-accounts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Why there are two users showing in uptime command results?](https://superuser.com/questions/148423/why-there-are-two-users-showing-in-uptime-command-results)

My MBP reports other users, but I'm the only one using this laptop:

> $:> uptime
>
> *19:30  up 13 days, 16 mins, **3 users**, load averages: 0.38 1.23 1.28*

Who are the other 2 users?

Comment: Does the "who" command return anything? They're probably just accounts that are running some services for you..

Answer (score 1):

They are just system accounts used for background services. You can view a list of all logged in users with the `users` command or the `who` command. Don't be surprised if it lists users more than once, that just means that user account has multiple login sessions running.

You can also use the `ps` command to view a list of processes running on your system, including which user account each is running under. This might help you get a better picture of what each account is used for.

Comment: the users command will not show root or service users, just real, logged in users - which might be what the OP needs, but will still show just one user, not 3.

Comment: @Traveling The one day I don't have access to my nix box is the one day I need to verify command output, go figure.

Comment: may I recommend Cygwin for your Windows box? That way you are never too far away from the *nix commands :)

Comment: @Traveling Both commands produced an empty line on my cygwin install, and the man pages aren't the most descriptive about this behavior. ;)

Answer (score 0):

These are not real users. Xserver or printserver or processes.

Comment: Why down voted?

Answer (score 0):

Well, one would be your user, another would be 'root' - the user your system uses to run its services. One more might be another service runner. The easiest way to find out would be to run

> ps u -A

and look at the first column - it'll tell you who's running what.

Answer (score 0):

The BSD *uptime* command takes its user count from the *utmp* database. You can use `users`, `who`, `w` or `finger` to see all login sessions recorded by *utmp*.

Most likely, those three entries correspond to three Terminal windows you have opened; SSH and X11 sessions are registered in the same way. (I don't know if *utmp* applies to graphical logins on Mac OS X, but you can just see for yourself.)